# int() function in Fortran 77

Tags: int, fortran

I have come across a problem when I use the `int()` function. I have an real array `mEL` and I want to convert some of its components to integers for comparison with real array `COORDS`. I have to use `int()` due to rounding errors in `COORDS` array, so `ZERO` is not quite zero is `3.D-77` or similar:

```
      DO I = 1,nLines
          IF (int(mEL(I,1)).EQ.int(COORDS(1,1)) .AND.
 1              int(mEL(I,2)).EQ.int(COORDS(2,1)) .AND. 
 2              int(mEL(I,3)).EQ.int(COORDS(3,1))) THEN

          .....do something
```

The problem is that during the run the outcome of `int(COORDS(1,1))` changes but the value of `COORDS(1,1)` is the same. For example:

```
COORDS(1,1) = 1829.0000000
```

During 1000 runs I get `int(COORDS(1,1))=1829`. However, after some runs I get:
`int(COORDS(1,1))=1828`! but `COORDS(1,1)=1829`!

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Do you really mean to have such a large acceptable difference between the two values?

Comment: No I don't want. That's why I want to avoid it. The problem is that int(COORDS(1,1)) sometimes is equal to 1828 but COORDS(1,1) is 1829.0000, so I was expecting that int(COORDS(1,1)) would be 1829...

Comment: Well `int` truncates so it's possible that if `coords(1,1)` is equal to (approximately) `1828.9999999999` then it would be displayed (under certain formatting options) as `1829.0000000` or even as `1829` but truncate (correctly) to `1828`.  Nothing you've told us excludes that possibility.  Is `coords(1,1)` updated during the run ?

Comment: @jpcgandre: I meant that there could be a difference of almost 1 between `mEL` and `coords` that is still accepted by your use of `int`, do you really want such a difference between *those* tow values?

Comment: The true value of `coords(1,1)` should be `1829` and will never change during the run. However, you are right maybe there's some precision error in `coords(1,1)`. I don't know the precision of `coords(1,1)` which I cannot control. When I ask to print its value `write(*,*)` it shows `1829.00000000000` the same as for the corresponding value of `mEL` array. However when I use `if mEL(I,1).eq.COORDS(1,1)` and they appear to be equal I don't get a true value so that's why I use int() function but as you reminded me int(1828.99999999999) is 1828 and not 1829 as I want. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'll try with `NINT` instead

Comment: To compare reals `a` and `b`, how about: `if ( abs(a-b) < small ) ) then... `, where `small` is some suitable small value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An introduction to the topic can be found in the section "Safe Comparisons" from article [The Perils of Floating Point](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm)

So for your code, you can use

```
      REAL EPS 
      PARAMETER (EPSILON = .000001)

      DO I = 1,nLines
          IF ((abs(mEL(I,1) - COORDS(1,1)) .LT. EPS )  .AND.
 1            (abs(mEL(I,2) - COORDS(2,1)) .LT. EPS )  .AND.
 2            (abs(mEL(I,3) - COORDS(3,1)) .LT. EPS )) THEN

          .....do something

          ENDIF
      ENDDO
```

You can even use something like `abs(mEL(I,1) - COORDS(1,1)) .LT. (abs(mEL(I,1))* EPS )`
or `abs(mEL(I,1) - COORDS(1,1)) .LT. (abs(mEL(I,1) + COORDS(1,1))* EPS )` if you want relative difference rather then absolute one